i130-i485 joint filing for parent
I plan to file for i130/i485 concurrent application for my mom who is staying with me in USA and has no plans to go back to India. My spouse will be the joint sponsor and provide affidavit of support.
My mom will be living mostly with my sibling in another state. I want to know which address( mine as the petitioner or sibling) should I fill under 12a ( beneficiary physical address)for i130 form?

You should fill the address where the beneficiary is physically staying. Basically, your mom's address - wherever it is that she lives.
